# Ravendb - Patching a List of Strings

Tags: ravendb

Using Ravendb (build 960) I am attempting to perform a bulk update on a set of documents to replace a single value in list of strings. I used [Google Group Question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/5qYWsq_ny0M) as base for the code, as the request was the nearly identical, but for some reason they were able to get theirs to work while mine errors out. I have composed the following sample console application to demo the issue.

```
public class Document
{
    public const string OLD_NAME = "Label A";
    public const string NEW_NAME = "Label B";

    public Document()
    {
        Labels = new List<string> { OLD_NAME };
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Labels { get; set; }
}

public class Document_By_Labels : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Document>
{
    public Document_By_Labels()
    {
        Map = leads => from doc in leads select new {doc.Labels};
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore
        {
            Url = "http://localhost:8081",
            DefaultDatabase = "RavendbPatchStringListTest"
        }.Initialize();
        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof (Program).Assembly, store);

        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            var s = new Document();
            session.Store(s);
            session.SaveChanges();

            var d = session.Load<Document>(s.Id);
            var m = session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(d);
        }

        store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Document/By/Labels",
                                             new IndexQuery {Query = string.Format("Labels:\"{0}\"", Document.OLD_NAME)},
                                             new[]
                                             {
                                                 new PatchRequest
                                                 {
                                                     Type = PatchCommandType.Modify,
                                                     Name = "Labels",
                                                     AllPositions = true,
                                                     Nested =
                                                         new[]
                                                         {
                                                             new PatchRequest
                                                             {
                                                                 Type = PatchCommandType.Remove,
                                                                 Value = new RavenJValue(Document.OLD_NAME)
                                                             },
                                                             new PatchRequest
                                                             {
                                                                 Type = PatchCommandType.Add,
                                                                 Value = new RavenJValue(Document.NEW_NAME)
                                                             }
                                                         }
                                                 }
                                             }, allowStale: true);
    }
}
```

When I run I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJValue' to type 'Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject'.
   at Raven.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert[U](RavenJToken token, Boolean cast) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\Extensions.cs:line 131
   at Raven.Json.Linq.Extensions.Convert[U](RavenJToken token) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\Extensions.cs:line 116
   at Raven.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value[U](RavenJToken value) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Abstractions\Json\Linq\Extensions.cs:line 24
   at Raven.Database.Json.JsonPatcher.ModifyValue(PatchRequest patchCmd, String propName, RavenJToken property) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Json\JsonPatcher.cs:line 138
   at Raven.Database.Json.JsonPatcher.Apply(PatchRequest patchCmd) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Json\JsonPatcher.cs:line 61
   at Raven.Database.Json.JsonPatcher.Apply(PatchRequest[] patch) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Json\JsonPatcher.cs:line 30
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.<>c__DisplayClassc1.<ApplyPatch>b__be(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 1150
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 330
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.ApplyPatch(String docId, Nullable`1 etag, PatchRequest[] patchDoc, TransactionInformation transactionInformation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:line 1131
   at Raven.Database.Impl.DatabaseBulkOperations.<>c__DisplayClass2.<UpdateByIndex>b__1(String docId, TransactionInformation tx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Impl\DatabaseBulkOperations.cs:line 42
   at Raven.Database.Impl.DatabaseBulkOperations.<>c__DisplayClassa.<PerformBulkOperation>b__5(IStorageActionsAccessor actions) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Impl\DatabaseBulkOperations.cs:line 80
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.ExecuteBatch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 376
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Batch(Action`1 action) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Storage.Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 337
   at Raven.Database.Impl.DatabaseBulkOperations.PerformBulkOperation(String index, IndexQuery indexQuery, Boolean allowStale, Func`3 batchOperation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Impl\DatabaseBulkOperations.cs:line 75
   at Raven.Database.Impl.DatabaseBulkOperations.UpdateByIndex(String indexName, IndexQuery queryToUpdate, PatchRequest[] patchRequests, Boolean allowStale) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Impl\DatabaseBulkOperations.cs:line 40
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Respond>b__0(String index, IndexQuery query, Boolean allowStale) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line 47
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.OnBulkOperation(IHttpContext context, Func`4 batchOperation) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line 64
   at Raven.Database.Server.Responders.DocumentBatch.Respond(IHttpContext context) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\Responders\DocumentBatch.cs:line 46
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.DispatchRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 550
   at Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer.HandleActualRequest(IHttpContext ctx) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Server\HttpServer.cs:line 316
```

While I believe the believe the process is correct I must be missing something otherwise it wouldn't be erroring out.

Please note there is no name on the above nested patches as I have tried a many different combos with the same error. Examples of attempts: "", "$values", "Labels". Same error each time and as a list of strings does not seem to have a Name I left it out in the above on purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking how to do the same thing recently. It sounds like it isn't possible to use the current patching API to change a string array.

See the discussion I've been having here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/5qYWsq_ny0M

Comment: While not the answer I was looking for it seems to be the only answer at the moment. Thank you.